# ¿Modificar JLabel desde otra clase?

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos

tengo una duda muy basica pero que no consigo entender,

tengo una ventana con un JLabel y un JButton y cuando pulso el boton cambio el texto del label.

```
public class NewClass extends JFrame{
public NewClass(){
    setSize(300,300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton boton = new JButton("boton");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("label");
    add(boton);
    add(label);

    Oyenteboton oyente = new Oyenteboton();
    boton.addActionListener(oyente);

    oyente.setlabel(label);
    }
 }
```

pero el actionlistener esta en otra clase

```
class Oyenteboton implements ActionListener {

JLabel label;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.label.setText(e.getActionCommand());

}

void setlabel(JLabel label) {
    this.label=label;
}
}
```

¿porque cuando modifico el label dentro de la clase Oyenteboton, cambia el label de NewClass?¿que relacion hay entre estos dos JLabel?

Answer (score 1):

En la clase `NewClass`, `oyente` es un `ActionListener` que guarda una referencia a un `JLabel`, y al ejecutarse su método `actionPerformed()` cambia el texto de ese `Jlabel`.

La instancia del `Jlabel` se le setea pasándole uno desde fuera de la clase utilizando el método `setLabel()`.

La clase `NewClass` crea un botón `JButton`, un label `JLabel`, y a `oyente` (`Oyenteboton` que implementa `ActionListener`).
A `oyente` le dice que internamente guarde la referencia al label.
Y Luego le dice al botón que agregue a `oyente` como uno de sus `ActionListeners`.

```
JButton boton = new JButton("boton"); // Se crean los objetos
JLabel label = new JLabel("label");
Oyenteboton oyente = new Oyenteboton();

oyente.setlabel(label); // Se setea el label de oyente con el JLabel recien creado

boton.addActionListener(oyente); // Se le agrega al botón el ActionListener oyente
```

Cuando se selecciona el botón, esté avisa a todos sus `ActionListeners`, incluido `oyente`, del evento llamando a su método `actionPerformed()`.

Cuando le llega el turno y se ejecuta el `actionPerformed()` de `oyente`, este le cambia el texto a su `JLabel` interno, que viene a ser el creado por `NewClass`.

```
this.label.setText(e.getActionCommand());
```

Comment: mi duda es, cuando ocurre el actionperformed y modifica el texto  del jlabel, el jlabel que es modificado es el que se encuentra dentro de la clase oyenteboton.

Comment: mi duda es que cuado ocurre el evento no deberia modificarse solo el jlabel al que hace referencia? o este esta conectado de alguna forma con el jlabel dentro de newclass?

Comment: No es que está conectado, es el mismo. Vos lo seteaste al hacer  `oyente.setlabel(label);`  dentro de NewClass.

Comment: perdon por la insitencia pero este metodo                                                    void setlabel(JLabel label) {
    this.label=label;
}                                                                                                                                       no viene a significar que a this.label se le asigna el contenido de label? aun asi se consideran el mismo?                                                                                    perdon si es algo muy basico pero me tortura el no saber

Comment: Significa eso mismo. Pero al decir "contenido" podemos estar pensando cosas diferentes. "Contenido" no es el texto, es un JLabel completo, el que recibe como parámetro. En tu programa el JLabel se crea con `new` en NewClass, y luego se pasa como parametro a oyente con setlabel().

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios , lo tengo mas claro ahora.